# Exportar archivo Excel con PHP - Error de formato al abrir archivo

Tags: php, excel

Al exportar un archivo excel con php, el archivo no puedo abrirlo porque me manda un error de formato.

Cabe destacar que estoy intentándolo abrir con **Excel 2013**

Este es el error:

> **EXCEL NO PUEDE ABRIR ESTE ARCHIVO.**
>
> "Es posible que el formato o la extension de este no sean validos. Compruebe que el archivo no se ha dañado y que la extension del mismo coincide con el formato del archivo"

Este es mi código:

```
<?php

include('C:/xampp/htdocs/LOGEC/core/conexion/conexion.php');
if($_GET['fecha_inicio'] and $_GET ['fecha_termino']){

$fecha_inicio = $_GET['fecha_inicio'];
$fecha_termino = $_GET['fecha_termino'];


$consulta = pg_query($conn, "SELECT a.name ... FROM ...");

$output = '';


if(pg_num_rows($consulta)>0){
  $output.= '<table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Nº Orden</th>
              <th>Cliente O.S</th> ...
            </tr>
  ';
  while($avance = pg_fetch_array($consulta)){
    $output.= '
              <tr>
                   <td>' . $avance['n_orden']. '</td>
                   <td>' . $avance['cliente_os']. '</td> ....
              </tr>
    ';
  }
  $output.= '</table>';
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="S.O desde '.$fecha_inicio.' hasta '.$fecha_termino.' (con inventario).xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    echo $output;
  }
}

?>
```

Por ultimo si existe la posibilidad de omitir ese mensaje al abrir porque los contenidos del documento no afectan en lo mas mínimo.

Comment: ¿Podrías reducir el código a un [mcve]? Actualmente hay tanto código a mirar que da cierto vértigo asomarse a él.

Comment: Reducido @fedorqui

Comment: Hola tuve el mismo problema que todo funciona bien y a ya con el archivo descargado excel no lo puede abrir a final de cuentas tenia que ver con que mi codigo agregaba algo al archivo al descargarlo que no debia ir, un opcion que me funciono muy bien es usar la etiqueta download de HTML eso si funciona solo en chrome pero si tienes opcion es una buena solucion

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de que Excel interpreta correctamente una tabla HTML como si fuera un archivo de Excel no deja de mostrar esta advertencia. Si en el archivo que estas exportando no tenes necesidad de utilizar funciones de excel lo mas conveniente es que lo exportes como CSV.

**¿que es CSV?**

Comma separated values (CSV) es un formato de archivo de texto que se puede utilizar para intercambiar datos de una hoja de cálculo entre aplicaciones. Cada línea de un archivo CSV de texto representa una fila de una hoja de cálculo. Cada celda de una fila de hoja de cálculo suele ir separada por una coma (,) o un punto y coma (;).

Proba el siguiente ejemplo, si te da buenos resultados podes adaptar la misma logica a tu caso.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file2.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo "N de orden; Cliente\n";
echo "0000001; Test 01 \n";
echo "0000002; Test 02 \n";
echo "0000003; Test 03 \n";
```

En caso de que tus registros puedan contener el caracter que se usa como separador (punto y coma en este ejemplo) deberias incluir el texto entre comillas.

Answer (score 0):

concuerdo con **Max Dominguez**

Pero si realmente deseas exportar un archivo excel te recomiendo usar [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), esto agrega un poco de dificultad a tu código pero lo hace más robusto.

Para facilitarme un poco el trabajo, desarrolle un helper, el cual usando funciones anónimas minimiza en algo el trabajo de crear worksheets. También te ayuda con la descarga, lo puedes descargar como `xls` o `xlsx`, este helper lo puedes encontrar [aquí](https://gist.github.com/bvelastegui/0baf3e71680f546818114b1773eeb58e)

Así quedaría tu código usando **PHPExcel** y mi **helper**

```
<?php
include('C:/xampp/htdocs/LOGEC/core/conexion/conexion.php');
include('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
include('class/Excel.php');

if ($_GET['fecha_inicio'] and $_GET ['fecha_termino'])
{
    $fecha_inicio = $_GET['fecha_inicio'];
    $fecha_termino = $_GET['fecha_termino'];

    $consulta = pg_query($conn, "SELECT a.name ... FROM ...");

    if (pg_num_rows($consulta) > 0)
    {
        $excel = new Excel("S.O_desde_{$fecha_inicio}_hasta_{$fecha_termino} (con inventario)");
        $excel->sheet('Worksheet', function (PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet) use ($consulta)
        {
            $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Nº Orden');
            $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Cliente O.S');
            $row = 2;
            while ($avance = pg_fetch_array($consulta))
            {
                $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row, $avance['n_orden']);
                $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, $avance['cliente_os']);
                $row++;
            }
        });
        //aquí defines la extensión de descarga
        //Soporta xls y xlsx          
        $excel->download('xlsx');
    }
}
```

Comment: Bryan Velastegui. Excelente hermano. Estuve un buen tiempo buscando para hacer esto y conseguí la solución que aportas. Sencilla, fácil de entender. Descarga super rápido el archivo .xlsx